# How to read text file data and display in dataGridView with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am new to reading from and writing to text files. I need to read the file and store the data of each cell in their respective arrays.

My text file has this character: "|" for column separators. The first column is string based,and the second and third columns are integer based. In the dataGridView there are four columns, the fourth column being the 2nd column percentage out of the total of both 2nd and 3rd columns.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim teamName As String = ""
    Dim gamesWon As Integer = 0
    Dim gamesLost As Integer = 0
    Dim percentOfGamesWon As Double = (gamesWon + gamesLost) * gamesWon / 100%

    Sub reader()
        Dim textLine As String = ""
        Dim SplitLine() As String
        Using objReader As New StreamReader("C:\Users\WORK\Documents\text files\ALE.txt")
           Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
              teamName = objReader.ReadLine()
              gamesWon = objReader.ReadLine()
              gamesLost = objReader.ReadLine()
              textLine = teamName & "|" & gamesWon & "|" & gamesLost & "|" & percentOfGamesWon
              SplitLine = Split(textLine, " ")
              Me.grdDisplay.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
          Loop
       End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
       reader()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Edit:** I changed the code as I noticed I did not include the variables teamName, gamesWon, gamesLost, and percentOfGamesWon

I, however, still have an error. I cannot use the objReader.Readline() with neither gamesWon, and gamesLost.

Comment: OleDB could read it into a DataTable so you can just bind it to your DGV.  Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour]...there are more than a few details missing

Comment: I am evidentally no good at wording my problems, i know. I have not used OleDB. I am supposed to take the data and display it in a DGV and doing this manually.

Comment: Maybe some code showing what you have tried and how you are doing it with a problem description would help. Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].

Comment: @Plutonix Added vb code.

Comment: Swell, now is there a problem?  does it work?  is there an error?  if so, what is it? What is the question?

Comment: @Plutonix I re-edited my code to include lines that I should have included already. My error states the following: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "Boston|93|69" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign whole data lines to the individual variables.  Instead, you need to split the value returned by `ReadLine` and convert the parts to the appropriate data type.  Adding `Option Strict On` will also help (either at the top of the file or in the project compile options).  You could also minimize the scope of your variables - they don't need to be declared at class level.

```
Sub reader()
    Using objReader As New StreamReader("C:\Users\WORK\Documents\text files\ALE.txt")
       Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
          Dim line As String = objReader.ReadLine()
          Dim splitLine() As String = line.Split("|")
          Dim teamName As String = splitLine(0)
          Dim gamesWon As Integer = CInt(splitLine(1))
          Dim gamesLost As Integer = CInt(splitLine(2))
          Dim percentOfGamesWon As Double = gamesWon / (gamesWon + gamesLost) * 100
          Me.grdDisplay.Rows.Add(teamName, gamesWon, gamesLost, percentOfGamesWon)
      Loop
   End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! If I were to sort the DGV by percentOfGamesWon in a descending order, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: I am honestly not sure how to implement sorting by percentOfGamesWon

Comment: I have sorted it with `grdDisplay.Sort(grdDisplay.Columns(3), ListSortDirection.Descending)`